# Loky Initializer (JobLib backend)

Tags: python, joblib

The [Advanced Executor Setup](https://loky.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/reuseable_executor.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-reuseable-executor-py) example from the Loky docs is failing when I try to run it.

I get the following:

```
$ python loky_init.py
[LokyProcess-1] init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loky_init.py", line 27, in <module>
    assert executor.submit(return_initializer_status).result() == 'initialized'
AssertionError
[LokyProcess-2] init
```

system:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
>>> loky.__version__
'2.5.1'
$ uname -a
Darwin dstuebe 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I posted an [issue](https://github.com/joblib/loky/issues/215) on the github project but have received no help yet.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes - looks like they moved the project under a project account.
Here is the update issue where Tom responded: https://github.com/joblib/loky/issues/215